# Is there a good resource that lists all conference committees in the current Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress

Conference committees are used to resolve difference between the two chambers of Congress. Even an astute observer may miss the creation of conference committees unless they regularly read the Record or similar type of document of Congress.

Is there a good resource to identify all conference committees that have already occurred in the current Congress? If not, is there a good resource for past Congresses? (By past Congresses I mean not the 116th Congress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a good resource to identify all conference committees that have already occurred in the current Congress? If not, is there a good resource for past Congresses? (By past Congresses I mean not the 116th Congress).

No, at least not that I could find. However, if the conference committee produced a report, the report is listed at [United States Congress Conference Reports](https://conferencereport.gpo.gov/).

Partial list:

> National Defense Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2020
>   Congress:116th Congress 1st Session Report Number:116-333
>   Date:12/10/2019 8:05:00 AM Bill Number:S. 1790
>
> Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2019
>   Congress:116th Congress 1st Session Report Number:116-9
>   Date:2/14/2019 8:32:17 AM Bill Number:H.J. Res. 31
>
> Agriculture Improvement Act of 2018
>   Congress:115th Congress 2nd Session Report Number:115-1072
>   Date:12/11/2018 11:10:00 AM Bill Number:H.R. 2
>
> Department of Defense, Labor, Health and Human Services, and Education   Appropriations Act, 2019, and Continuing Appropriations Act, 2019
>   Congress:115th Congress 2nd Session Report Number:115-952
>   Date:9/14/2018 1:20:00 PM Bill Number:H.R. 6157
>
> ...

---

There is an API for accessing information but I am not familiar with what is available. *See* [New govinfo API](https://www.govinfo.gov/features/api).